# Controlling the dynamics of nonlinear systems with an unknown steady-state

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I have repeatedly raised this, in my opinion, an extremely accurately formulated question here, but I have not received a qualified answer to it.

Let's take a simple gradient dynamical system:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}$

where $f=e^{-(x-x_*)^2}$ and $x_*$ - constant, that constant defining the position of the maximum.

The transition process in such a system is a transition from state $x(0)$ to state $x_*$.

We assume that we don't know the value $x_*$ in advance, as well as the function $f$ itself. How to make sure that transients in such a system always occur exponentially?

We can do anything: add control signals or add auxiliary variables.